# Something has taken over my computer

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I started up my computer and a program seems to be spawning a popup:

> "c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe /c c:\users\jjs\appdata\local\temp\memslafo"
>
> Do you want to allow the program to make changes to this computer?

When I click "no" it continues to spawn the popup.

I have deleted the *memslafo* program (it is of type: "application") - but a process keeps on regenerating it.

Does anyone know how I can kill this process once and for all? I have Norton Antivirus installed - but it hasn't detected a virus.

Answer (score 5):

[Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org) is usually pretty good at finding these things.

(no connection except as a satisfied user)

Comment: Also, if the infection prevents you from running malwarebytes, you may need to run it in safe mode with networking.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not suitable for stackoverflow.
To that extent I don't believe there is any StackExchange forum that will suitable to ask this question as the answer depend on your situation and requires extensive followups.

The behavior seems very much like a virus but it will need further investigation.

As a short answer, First try this :

Install  [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials) and perform a full scan with it. If its a virus it should be detected and removed.

If that doesn't fix your problem, do this :

Go to a website dedicated to fixing computer virus like HijackThis based forum, http://www.hijackthis.de/ and ask for help there. They will ask for a hijackthis log and the forum will have detailed instruction on how to get the log and how to post asking for help. Follow the rules and you will be get help soon.

Best of luck with your infection.

PS : That behavior in it self doesn't imply a virus but it is very likely. It could also be a malfunctioning program but the help forum linked about will give you the definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

Few possible solutions:

Try to use ccleaner and run bith full clean and registry clean http://en.softonic.com/s/cc-cleaner also try full scan of your computer if havent already ...

Search for file which caries process name and delete it.

If that doesnt help you can always reinstall entire windows.

best wishes

Comment: running a registry cleaner is usually the last step, not the first. If you do this first before removing the infection, you run the risk of causing damage.